# What are the footprints a magento module can leave in the magento system?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, delete, package, uninstall

I installed a module/extension but it does not work well for our needs.

I want to completely delete the module with all its footprints.

I removed the following:

1. code pool - deleted the folder related to that module under community folder,
2. deleted design files at design/frontend and design/adminhtml,
3. deleted email template files of that module at locale//template/email/,
4. deleted Namespace_ModuleName.xml at etc/modules folder,
5. removed configuration variable values of that module at core_config_data table,
6. deleted module entry at core_resource table,
7. deleted all tables created by that module by looking sql file of the module

**what else I need to remove to uninstall the module completely**

> Am I doing correct or is there any other standard way to uninstall
>   magento extentsion ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the personal list I made up over the years:

- `app/code/<codePool>` folder
- `app/etc/modules` file
- `app/locale` translation and email files
- `app/design` layout and template files
- `js` libraries
- `lib` libraries
- `skin` js, css and images files
- `shell` scripts
- extra non native folders

Regarding database:

- Tables created by the module
- `core_config_data` entries
- `core_resource` entry
- Possible extra columns added to native Magento tables
- Possible attributes added to native Magento entities (**this is a very important one, especially if a backend model is used, removing the files without removing the attribute could potentially break the websote**)

One useful module I use to properly uninstall my personal modules is https://github.com/magento-hackathon/MageTrashApp it lets you create uninstall scripts for both files and database for your modules then you can uninstall them from the backend.

Comment: @rapheal  how to find the "Possible attributes added to native Magento entities"

Comment: @manokarthickkarthick well you'll have to check the sql install scripts of the module to find out

Comment: @rapheal leaving the attributes will crash all the pages of the system? what are the pages?

Comment: @manokarthickkarthick well it will only crash if a backend model is linked to the attribute (as the file of the backend model has been deleted). For the pages it depends, if it's a product attribute it may crash category and product pages, if it's a customer attribute it may crash customer pages etc...